# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unshift')

Tags: node.js, postman

```
router.put('/experience', 
    [
        auth, 
        [
          check('title', 'Title is required')
            .not()
            .isEmpty(),
          check('company', 'Company is required')
            .not()
            .isEmpty(),
          check('from', 'From date is required')
            .not()
            .isEmpty()  
        ] 
    ], 
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const {
            title,
            company,
            location,
            from,
            to,
            current,
            description
        } = req.body;

        const newExp = {
            title,
            company,
            location,
            from,
            to,
            current,
            description
        }

        try {
            const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

            profile.experience.unshift(newExp);

            await profile.save();

            res.json(profile);

        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server Error ' + err.message);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If no profile gets found or no experience found in that profile the value will be undefined so this error occurs. Any JavaScript method with undefined value will give this error, try adding this:

```
if(profile) {
 profile.experience.unshift(newExp);
}
```

OR

```
if(!profile) {
 res.status(404).send("No profile found")
 return
}
```